# Dynamic Select from table at database link

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbuilder

I want to select data from a table in a remote database which I have its database link in a variable, how I can do that?

My query is something like this:

```
select `table_column` form any_table@:any_variable_1 where any_column= :any_variable_2;
```

Note:
any_variable_1 is a string variable contains the name of the database link
any_variable_2 is a string variable contains the string for filtering 
* this code is to be executed in function in powerbuilder 8 or 9
* the database which I am connecting to is oracle 11 g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string ls_sql

        ls_sql="Select column_name  from table_name@"+var_db_link_name+""+&
                  " where column_name='"+var_value+"' and another_column_name='"+another_var+"'"

        DECLARE var_cursor DYNAMIC CURSOR FOR SQLSA ;

        PREPARE SQLSA FROM :ls_sql ;

        OPEN DYNAMIC var_cursor ;
        FETCH var_cursor INTO :another_var ;//another_var holds the result of the cursor
        CLOSE var_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
  l_var number(10); -- data type you are expecting from the table_column column
  l_cursor sys_refcursor;
  l_any_variable_1 varchar2(50) := 'YOUR_DBLINK_HERE';
  l_any_variable_2 varchar2(50);
BEIGN
  open l_cursor for 'select table_column from any_table@ '|| 
                                l_any_variable_1 ||
                    ' where any_column = :any_variable_2' 
                      using l_any_variable_2;
  loop
    fetch l_cursor into l_var;
    exit when l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_var);
  end loop;
  close l_cursor;
END;
```